# Difference Between Hadoop Mapreduce(Java) and RHadoop mapreduce

Tags: machine-learning, r, apache-hadoop, map-reduce

I understand Hadoop MapReduce and its features but I am confused about R MapReduce.

One difference I have read is that R utilizes maximum RAM. So do perform parallel processing integrated R with Hadoop.

### My doubt is:

1. R can do all stats, math and data science related stuff, but why R MapReduce?
2. Is there any new task I can achieve by using R MapReduce instead of Hadoop MapReduce? If yes, please specify.
3. We can achieve the task by using R with Hadoop (directly) but what is the importance of MapReduce in R and how it is different from normal MapReduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rhadoop](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop) (the part you are interested in is now called [rmr2](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rmr2)) is simply a client API for MapReduce written in R. You invoke MapReduce using R package APIs, and send an R function to the workers, where it is executed by an R interpreter locally. But it is otherwise exactly the same MapReduce.

You can call anything you like in R this way, but no R functions are themselves parallelized to use MapReduce in this way. The point is simply that you can invoke M/R from R. I don't think it somehow lets you do anything more magical than that.

Comment: Can we do Regresssion,clustering,classifications using Rmr...... If it is possible then we can do using R directly.. only because of Parallelism we are using Rmr.. If i am correct.. Is there any main Difference between Hadoop Mapreduce and R mapreduce (apart from Parallelism)...

Comment: rmr is a framework for running R functions in MapReduce. That is the thing it lets you do that you could not do before. It is not a library of new statistical functions of course.

Comment: Then any other  specific feature where hadoop mapreduce can't handle?.....